# Hadoop Streaming using C

Tags: c, hadoop-streaming, word-count

I have to write a Hadoop Streaming program using just C. I have been trying to find a WordCount program online but without any success. I would be grateful if someone would share any C Hadoop Streaming program

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just googled and found this [page](https://rcc.fsu.edu/docs/hadoop-programming-arbitrary-languages) and [this](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%2B%2B_Programs_on_Hadoop) with different examples.